# How to deal with signs of woodworm in "live edge" wooden slab

Tags: finishing

I'm building a "live edge" shelf/table, and after I removed the bark, there are several exposed woodworm burrows right under the bark. They are quite deep (3-6mm), so I don't want remove all that wood.

I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with that: leave it as-is, or fill with something (with what?) and sand flush?.

The finish will be a stain + oil/varnish.

Comment: Are you certain they are gone?  What kind of wood is it? (May help ID the pest).  Possibly related post: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/821/protecting-wood-from-powder-post-beetles

Comment: It's (supposedly) kiln-dried walnut, I don't think any larvae insect could survive being kiln-dried. Also, the exposed burrows seem to be without any "surprises".

Comment: Related, maybe someone can recommend something https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/7585/5393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave them for character or fill them as you prefer, it's entirely up to you.

If you want to fill I'd suggest filled/tinted epoxy as it's cheap and easy to do and can be customised to suit. See [Large hole filler products, what is available](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/large-hole-filler-products-what-is-available/3809#3809) for more info.

**Note** if you have the least worries about the insects still being active then you should treat the wood with a proprietary insecticide made for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer you linked is also awesome, but I'm not sure if epoxy+sawdust would be stainable... Or how the oil/varnish will look over it. Guess I'll have to experiment with some off-cuts first.