# How to be sure that there are no live woodworms in my oak boards?

Tags: wood, wood-repair, surface-preparation

I discovered few 10-15 holes on one of my oak plans I use to build a table. How can I assure that there are no worm left alive to ruin my future table. I cannot plane them.[image: oak with woodworm signs]

Comment: You cannot be sure the board has no active 'worm' inside, regardless of whether the bore/exit holes you see are all obviously old. And unfortunately pesticides can be the *least* effective method to eradicate, since they often can't reach the larvae deep in the wood and when applied to the surface to prevent re-infestation there is incredibly shallow penetration (as there is with almost everything we apply to wood).

Comment: As one smart guys said there are only two things certain in the world: death and taxes ;) I am looking for a common sense approach. I am afraid that I do not have access to a large freezer or kiln.

Comment: Well what seems to make sense will vary from person to person. I've brought small pieces of wood that I knew had active woodworm into my own home, knowing I'd be using the microwave or freezer to be absolutely certain to kill off remaining larvae, but I know many experienced woodworkers take the position that if there's the least chance a piece of wood has a current infestation and the piece is too big to freeze it's burned as firewood or thrown away, they just won't take the risk of it spreading.

Comment: All holes were dark which makes me believe they were old, before the wood was kiln dried. I guess I will take the risk and apply treatment and expect for the best. I could mark them and check if I see new one every 6 month (Alexa set a reminder to check table for new holes” ;)

Comment: *"I could mark them and check if I see new one every 6 month"* Yes that's something you can do. Others fill all current holes (doesn't have to be a hard filler, just coloured wax will do) then they know if they spot a hole anywhere down the line it's definitely new activity.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the bugs are already gone. (Bugs only stick around for a few years* - the holes they leave last forever) If you clean the board up and leave it for a while and see no further evidence of new holes or dust you can be reasonably safe in assuming they have gone.

(* See Graphus' comment on possible life spans)

If you think they are still alive, then you have three main options:

1. Heating
2. Cooling
3. Pesticides

**Heating**

If you have a big enough oven, or access to a kiln, heating to wood to a moderate temperature (ie about 56°C) will kill pretty much everything inside, very reliably

**Cooling**

If you have access to walk-in freezer, putting the boards in a plastic bag (optional - for humidity) and leaving them in there for several weeks will also kill most bugs.

**Pesticides**

Probably the most reasonable option available - you can buy pyrethrin spray designed for wood bugs that has a very fine tip applicator that can fit into the holes. Each hole needs to be sprayed. This can be time consuming, but I've found it very effective.

[image]

Comment: Can I use a heatgun? I already have one. Good part is that total number of holes is  around 8 after bit more planning. If not In get some spray. Thanks.

Comment: @sorin - no chance of heating the inside of the board up to temp without charring the outside with a heat gun. Spray would be the way to go i think

Comment: What we generically refer to as woodworm is the attack by a number of wood-boring insect pests, which each have slightly different breeding cycles. The rest of your Answer is dead on but I think you should edit the first paragraph because it is by no means true that they only stick around for a yea — 2-5 years is the figure most often quoted. Additionally any of the three or four most common species can re-infest the same wood generation after generation, which is how you get boards or pieces of ply that are half gone inside.

Comment: I ordered this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Barrettine-Woodworm-Killer-250ml/dp/B0166Q05HY and I will use a seringe or pipete to reach the 8-10 holes that I found. I will do this after planing and sanding the boards, 24h before applying the wax cover.

Comment: @graphus - fair enough. Edited post

Comment: Wouldn't a good thick varnishing on the finished piece of furniture also kill anything that might be still alive inside?

Comment: @Joe, no. Finishing is considered a good preventative against reinfestation however because wood-borers like to lay eggs on unfinished wood.